# Undefined method 'object' when using active model serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to assign attributes to my serializer, and i'm getting a "undefined local variable or method `object'" error

version: 0.10.1

This is what my serializer looks like:

```
class ImageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :item

  attributes :id, :image, :order, :url

  def url 
    object.image.url
  end
end
```

controller method:

```
def show
  @menu_item = MenuItem.find(params[:id])

  render json: @menu_item
end
```

Anyone know why i'm having this problem? I'm following this serializer guide at this link: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/serializers.md

Comment: That looks exactly how I do it. Which version of AMS are you using? Maybe include a snippet of your controller code that is using this serializer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I updated my question.

Comment: You seem to be trying to serialize a MenuItem, but the included serializer is for Image.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem but you may want to explicitly tell your controller which serializer to use like this: `render json: @menu_item, serializer: ImageSerializer`. I'm still on AMS 0.8.3 so some things may have changed. Without specifying a serializer AMS will do its best but there seems to be a disconnect between what you are rendering and the serializer you included in you question.